# Determine if SQLite3 transaction is active

Tags: sqlite

I am running an `END TRANSACTION` on my database and occasionally I get error

> #1 that "cannot commit - no transaction is active"

Is there a way to determine if a transaction is active before trying a commit? I have been tracking my `"BEGIN TRANSACTIONS"` by hand but I feel there is a better way.

I am using the C API

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to check this:

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html

According to the page, if you are in a transaction, `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

The interface you're looking for is actually implemented in this next version of sqlite as you can see in the notes: https://sqlite.org/draft/c3ref/txn_state.html

```
Determine the transaction state of a database

int sqlite3_txn_state(sqlite3*,const char *zSchema);

The sqlite3_txn_state(D,S) interface returns the current transaction state of schema S in database connection D. If S is NULL, then the highest transaction state of any schema on databse connection D is returned. Transaction states are (in order of lowest to highest):

SQLITE_TXN_NONE
SQLITE_TXN_READ
SQLITE_TXN_WRITE

If the S argument to sqlite3_txn_state(D,S) is not the name of a valid schema, then -1 is returned.
```

Comment: The explanation of [Read/Write transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) is confusing though. If this function returns '1' (Read Transaction) does that mean I can or cannot issue another `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement that would upgrade it to a write transaction?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I thought sqlite was always in a transaction, either explicitly created by you or implicitly created by sqlite:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

So I suppose the error means that it's not in a transaction that you initiated ... and if that's what you need to know, it seems OK for sqlite to expect you to keep up with it. Not terribly convenient of course, but I guess that's the cost of a simple API. =/

Answer (score -1):

In SQLite, transactions created using BEGIN TRANSACTION ... END TRANSACTION do not nest.

For nested transactions you need to use the SAVEPOINT and RELEASE commands.

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html

Comment: You are answering something about nesting which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood.
I thought you must had been keeping a count of how deeply nested the transactions were, which would obvioulsy get out of sync with SQLite if it didn't support it.

As far as I am aware there is no way to ask SQLite if it is in a transaction.